# Declaring CSV write globally

Tags: python

I have a script, but broken down it looks like this

```
import csv
#Global
writervariable = ''

def function1(): <--uses the writervariable.writerow
def function2():
def main():
    writervariable = csv.writer(file)
    function1()
    function2()
main()
```

I am getting the error str has no writerow method, which make sense, but I thought setting it to csv.writer would change its type.

When I was just prototyping my script, I did this all in one big chaos function, and it worked.

Adding minimal reproducible example:

```
import csv

writer = ''

def function1():
    writer.writerow(['data1', 'data2'])

def main():
    with open('TestFile', 'w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(['header1', 'header2'])
        function1()

main()
```

Comment: Please, post [mre].

Comment: https://youtu.be/_AEJHKGk9ns might be relevant

Comment: @buran I added the example in the main post

Comment: main is creating a local variable named writer that is masking the "global" one.  you need to put `global writer` statement inside main

Comment: pass `writer` as a parameter to `function1()`.. ie `function1(writer)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error because you actually have 2 `writervariable`s in 2 different scopes. One is a string in the global scope, and another one - a `csv.writer` in the scope of the `main()` function.

When you try to call `writervariable.writerow()` inside the `function1()`, this function can "see" the `writervariable` in the global scope, which is a string, but the scope of the main function is out of visibility.

What you want to do is to pass the `writervariable` from the `main()` function to `function1()` and then use it there:

```
def function1(csv_writer): <--uses the writervariable.writerow
    csv_writer.writerow()
def function2():
def main():
    writervariable = csv.writer(file)
    function1(writervariable)
    function2()
main()
```

Comment: I put this in my test function and it worked just as you showed. Thank you! Can you explain why setting the global variable in main() didn't prompt it to change type, or be picked up by the function called later in the script?

Comment: The scope of `function1()` is different from the scope of `main()`. When you defined a variable inside `main()`, that variable was not global and was not visible inside `function1()`. The visibility of variables depends on the scope. More info on resolution of names: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names